# How do I send a calendar event from the iphone calendar via an email or imessage?

Tags: iphone, messages, calendar, ios

I want to forward a specific calendar event from the iOS Calendar App to an email address or iMessage address or text message using my iPhone. I don't want to use the cloud or sync anything. I am using iOS 8.4 but would also be interested in how to do this in iOS 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use a contact in your address-book and add them as an invitee to the calendar event.

You will be prompted to send an invite to them.

*EDIT*: Previous link sucked.

Here are the steps circa **iOS 9**:

1. Launch the Calendar app on your iPhone or iPad
2. Either create a new event or tap an existing event that you'd like to share
3. Tap on the Edit button in the upper right hand corner
4. Tap Invitees. Add all the email addresses of the people you'd like to share the event with

*EDIT 2*: Added iOS 11 details.

Here are the steps circa **iOS 11**:

1. Launch the Calendar app on your iPhone or iPad
2. Either create a new event or tap and existing event that you'd like to share
3. Tap "Invitees"
4. Tap "Add invitees"
5. Either enter an email address, or tap the (+) at the right to select from your address book

Comment: Your link seems to be about iCloud on OSX, not the iPhone.

Comment: There is no Invitees option when I edit an event

Comment: @jjz The interface has changed since this posting. I will update for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Apple failed here, there is no way to actually forward an event from iOS/iPad OS but...

Normally when people create an event, they don't then forward it but rather simply add the new person to the invite list. Therefor I presume you mean forward an event you have received.

To forward the particulars of an event you can:

1. Tap on the Event
2. Tap on the Invitees
3. Tap the small envelope icon in the upper right (creates an email)
4. Delete the invitee list in the "To" field of the email
5. Type the email address of the person to whom you wish to forward the info
6. Tap "Send" in the upper right.

It is not truly forwarding the event but it does contain the event details.

Insane that Apple neglected this very common and needed feature in an otherwise rather decent product. If you think so too, please take the time to tell Apple with "need way to forward an event from iPhone Calendar" here:
https://www.apple.com/feedback/calendar.html

Comment: The worst part is that this feature actually exists on Mac! (right-click > mail event) It creates a link object ".ics" that you can copy/paste and drag/drop anywhere you like, and forwards the notes content. Not sure why they still don't have that on iOS...